# Performing a linear model in R of a single response with a single predictor from a large dataframe and repeat for each column

Tags: r, apply, lapply, lm, sapply

It might not be very clear from the title but what I wish to do is:

1. I have a dataframe df with, say, 200 columns and the first 80 columns are response variables (y1, y2, y3, ...) and the rest of 120 are predictors (x1, x2, x3, ...).
2. I wish to compute a linear model for each pair – `lm(yi ~ xi, data = df)`.
3. Many problems and solutions I have looked through online have a either a fixed response vs many predictors or the other way around, using `lapply()` and its related functions.

Could anyone who is familiar with it point me to the right step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
df <- mtcars
y <- names(df)[1:3]
x <- names(df)[4:7]

result <- expand_grid(x, y) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(frm = list(reformulate(x, y)),
         model = list(lm(frm, data = df))) 

result$model <- purrr::set_names(result$model, nm = paste0(result$y, " ~ ", result$x))

result$model[1:2]
#> $`mpg ~ hp`
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = frm, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           hp  
#>    30.09886     -0.06823  
#> 
#> 
#> $`cyl ~ hp`
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = frm, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           hp  
#>     3.00680      0.02168

map_df(result$model, tidy)
#> # A tibble: 24 x 5
#>    term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
#>    <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 (Intercept)  30.1      1.63       18.4   6.64e-18
#>  2 hp           -0.0682   0.0101     -6.74  1.79e- 7
#>  3 (Intercept)   3.01     0.425       7.07  7.41e- 8
#>  4 hp            0.0217   0.00264     8.23  3.48e- 9
#>  5 (Intercept)  21.0     32.6         0.644 5.25e- 1
#>  6 hp            1.43     0.202       7.08  7.14e- 8
#>  7 (Intercept)  -7.52     5.48       -1.37  1.80e- 1
#>  8 drat          7.68     1.51        5.10  1.78e- 5
#>  9 (Intercept)  14.6      1.58        9.22  2.93e-10
#> 10 drat         -2.34     0.436      -5.37  8.24e- 6
#> # ... with 14 more rows

map_df(result$model, glance)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 12
#>    r.squared adj.r.squared  sigma statistic  p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC
#>        <dbl>         <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     0.602         0.589   3.86     45.5  1.79e- 7     1  -87.6 181.  186. 
#>  2     0.693         0.683   1.01     67.7  3.48e- 9     1  -44.6  95.1  99.5
#>  3     0.626         0.613  77.1      50.1  7.14e- 8     1 -183.  373.  377. 
#>  4     0.464         0.446   4.49     26.0  1.78e- 5     1  -92.4 191.  195. 
#>  5     0.490         0.473   1.30     28.8  8.24e- 6     1  -52.7 111.  116. 
#>  6     0.504         0.488  88.7      30.5  5.28e- 6     1 -188.  382.  386. 
#>  7     0.753         0.745   3.05     91.4  1.29e-10     1  -80.0 166.  170. 
#>  8     0.612         0.599   1.13     47.4  1.22e- 7     1  -48.3 103.  107. 
#>  9     0.789         0.781  57.9     112.   1.22e-11     1 -174.  355.  359. 
#> 10     0.175         0.148   5.56      6.38 1.71e- 2     1  -99.3 205.  209. 
#> 11     0.350         0.328   1.46     16.1  3.66e- 4     1  -56.6 119.  124. 
#> 12     0.188         0.161 114.        6.95 1.31e- 2     1 -196.  398.  402. 
#> # ... with 3 more variables: deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful. I wonder if it is possible to generate the output in 2 separate matrices (80 x 120), one for the coefficient term and the other its associated p-values.

Comment: I was glad to help. Try it this way `map_df(result$model, tidy)` or `map_df(result$model, glance)`

Comment: Both returned as 'Error: No tidy method for objects of class summary.lm'

Comment: I have the library(broom) ready, so not sure what went wrong

Comment: I have no error. Have a look, updated answer

Comment: Ah I have found my mistake. I have added summary(lm(...)) in the function earlier

Comment: Hi Yuriy, with the 'map_df()' function the response variable annotation is lost (e.g. mpg, cyl etc.). Is there a way to associate it back your (24 x 5) tibble and so I could use 'pivot_wider()' to reshape the data into the wide format I want?

Comment: solved. In case anyone is looking through the section, first pull out the response variables (# of rows = R) as a column and use `cbind()` to add that column to the output result (of different lengths, i.e. different # of rows, say W) and R would recycle the response variables over and over, as long as the W is a multiple of R.